# How can I make this parent-child relationship work?

Tags: mysql, parent-child, ireport

Using MySQL how can I make this hierarchy work?

- Parent's ID is 100. This Parent has a ParentID of 0.
- Child has an ID of 101. The ParentID is 100.
- SubEntity has an ID of 105.  The ParentID is 100.
- Child of Subentity has an ID of 106.  Their ParentID is 105.

This query will be plugged into iReport.  Currently the Subentity and it's children do not roll up into the Parent.

This is what I ended up going with:

```
`Select
case
when FC.ParentType = 'PARENT' then FC.FundCode
when FB.ParentType = 'PARENT' then FB.FundCode
when F.ParentType = 'PARENT' then F.FundCode
else 0 end as `ParentID`,
case
when FB.ParentType = 'SUBFUND' then FB.FundCode
when F.ParentType = 'SUBFUND' then F.FundCode
else 0 end as `SubfundID`,
case
when FB.ParentType = 'CHILD' then FB.FundCode
when F.ParentType = 'CHILD' then F.FundCode
else 0 end as `Children`,            
F.FundName     
From Fund F
join Fund FB on F.ParentId = FB.FundCode
join Fund FC on FB.ParentID = FC.FundCode`
```

Comment: To clarify, you have a record in Parent that relates back to the Parent ID of another row?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us, what have you already tried.

Comment: @YYY To try and answer both of your questions, the data is out of a Fund table.  The parent fund has children funds and a subfund which also has children funds.  Right now the report works in that the  Parent's children roll up.  However the subfund and it's children only roll up to the subfund where they need to roll up to the Parent as well. Right now I'm pulling all the funds out of the table with just basic criteria in the where clause

Comment: @Darvex See above, didn't know you couldn't reply to two people, Also thank you Nikola K for editing my question.

Comment: @nEWbie But are you trying to keep track of these relationships in the same table? As in, they're all in this same Fund table and there's relationships going whichever way from there?

Comment: @YYY I'm not sure I follow.  The relationships exist in the table as I have outlined above.  But since the relationship is flawed in that the subfund's children do not roll up to the ultimate Parent the report will not present the performance numbers correctly.

Comment: @nEWbie Okay, so they're all in the same table.  The alternative as I was trying to talk about it was if you had relationships defined in some other table that you were referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a static number governing how many levels this parent-child relationship has?

**Yes:** Use recursive `LEFT JOIN`s X times.

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN table t3
  ON t2.id = t3.parent_id
  ...
```

**No:** Accomplish this using separate queries until you have fleshed out your Parent/Child objects as far as you want. Make sure you have checks in place to avoid loops, ie. a child is a parent of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Recursive CTE** for this scenario.  Take a look at this link, it gives a good example.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: my bad, I didn't see mySQL - sorry!